# PyCharm type checker expected type 'None', got 'str' instead when using pandas dataframe.to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, types, pycharm, warnings

Using PyCharm 2021.2 (Community Edition) and Pandas 1.3.1, with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_csv("testfile.csv")
```

PyCharm will produce a Warning, highlight "testfile.csv", and display "Expected type 'None', got 'str' instead" when hovering over the Warning.

testfile.csv is created and no issues appear to be happening.

Is there a way to fix this? Does anyone know why this Warning appears?

Thanks

Answer (score 25):

This appears to be a bug in Pycharm that prevents it from properly interpreting `|`; the new operator for `typing.Union`.

If I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> while inside of the argument list of `to_csv`, I get this

[image]

Note that it thinks the argument is of type `None` (indicated by `: None`).

The problem is, this is the actual signature of the function:

```
def to_csv(
           self,
           path_or_buf: FilePathOrBuffer[AnyStr] | None = None,
           . . .
```

The type of the parameter is actually `FilePathOrBuffer[AnyStr] | None`, which prior to Python 3.10 would be `typing.Union[FilePathOrBuffer[AnyStr], None]` or simply `typing.Optional[FilePathOrBuffer[AnyStr]]`.

Pycharm apparently can't yet read fancy type hints, despite saying it supports Python 3.10.

---

It's pointed out in the comments that this appears to actually be `pandas`' fault. Apparently it's using `|` despite only claiming support for 3.8.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I should've also included that I am using Python 3.9 as well.

Comment: Ah, understood. Thanks again!

Comment: I created a ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50337. PEP 604 is supported by the IDE, though this specific example doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: This isn't pycharms fault, pandas is using a 3.10 feature in a version that is supposed to support 3.8

Answer (score 7):

You can suppress the PyCharm warning as follows:

```
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
df.to_csv("testfile.csv")
```

You can also add the `noinspection` comment at the start of a function or class to disable warnings within, but careful not to hide other real warnings. I prefer per-statement suppression only as needed.