# Expected type 'None', got 'str' instead, python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Have been trying to figure it out but can someone please tell me how to resolve this: (Building a flash card app)

```
def is_known():
    to_learn.remove(current_card)
    data_learnt = pandas.DataFrame(to_learn)
    data_learnt.to_csv("skip.csv")
```

the .to_csv() shows the error :Expected type 'None', got 'str' instead.

Why would it be none?

code:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("skip.csv")
to_learn = data.to_dict(orient="records")
current_card = {}


# ----------------BUTTON FUNCTIONS----------------#
def next_card():
    global current_card, flip_timer
    window.after_cancel(flip_timer)
    current_card = random.choice(to_learn)
    canvas.itemconfig(title_text, text="French", fill="black")
    canvas.itemconfig(word_text, text=current_card["French"], fill="black")
    canvas.itemconfig(card_bg, image=flash_front_img)
    flip_timer = window.after(3000, flip_card)


def flip_card():
    canvas.itemconfig(title_text, text="English", fill="white")
    canvas.itemconfig(word_text, text=current_card["English"], fill="white")
    canvas.itemconfig(card_bg, image=flash_back_img)


def is_known():
    to_learn.remove(current_card)
    data_learnt = pandas.DataFrame(to_learn)
    data_learnt.to_csv("skip.csv")
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example i.e. provide examples for all variables you are using.

Comment: This snippet should work properly. Most probably, error is due to the other part of the code. Can you share the other parts as well?

Comment: Yeah sure just did. Check that out

Comment: Are you using PyCharm? Because I've came across with an [Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50337) that states the same problem here.

Comment: Yes I am, came across that too but it didn't solve it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm type checker expected type 'None', got 'str' instead when using pandas dataframe.to\_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68787744/pycharm-type-checker-expected-type-none-got-str-instead-when-using-pandas-d)

Comment: Did you find the solution?